# AngularJS - Retrieving Data for Multiple Widgets in a Single AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, architecture, widget

I have an architectural question about data retrieval for multiple widgets.

I am building a large javascript application (a mini-SPA) with AngularJS.  I want to create a very modular Dashboard application with interactive widgets that the user can choose to include, exclude or reposition in the containers of the layout system.  The user can interact with each widget, causing an individual refresh of it’s data and more.  Each widget will be displaying very different data from other widgets.

---

So far architecturally, each widget will be represented by these AngularJS components:

- a **partial view template** (to show the user the data)
- a **controller** (to implement widget behavior and handle the success callback of the corresponding service)
- a **service** (to retrieve data with $http and return a promise object to the calling controller)

Thus each widget has the ability to pull it’s own data through an Angular Service calling a particular endpoint.

Now, when the user arrives on the Dashboard Page containing possibly 5 widgets, I don’t want to make 5 individual parallel AJAX calls to 5 different server endpoints.  That wouldn't be efficient; I'd like to reduce parallel requests to the server.

Instead, on arrival to the page, I’d rather make a single AJAX call by calling an endpoint that has aggregated all the data of the 5 widgets.

**QUESTION:** Supposing that the server can bundle/merge all the data from the 5 widgets in 1 JSON payload in a clever wrapper, then in the AngularJS application, how would I retrieve and distribute that data to the 5 widget controllers, so that they can initialize themselves with the fresh server data?

Of course, I’d want to retain the ability for any single widget to refresh only themselves.  Though behavior beyond arriving on the Dashboard page isn’t what I’m asking about in this question.

Maybe there are articles out there that talk about this, but I haven’t found one yet.

---

I have already thought of one architectural idea that I think is ‘good’, but I wonder if there are better solutions.

Possibility) In addition to the 5 Angular Services to make AJAX calls, introduce a 6th called WidgetAggregateService.  When it’s `retrieveAllAndBroadcast()` method is executed, this service would handle the success callback itself and then publish the payload to the 5 controllers using `$rootScope.$emit()`.  Thus the WidgetAggregateService would be using the Mediator Pattern (or PubSub Pattern) on $rootScope that the 5 controllers can subscribe to with `$rootScope.$on()`.  Each widget's controller can grab the relevant information in the aggregate data payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team and I came up with a solution…

**API Contract**

We have a developed a API contract that allows us to make requests to the server for 1 or more widgets (including passing relevant request arguments) that will return 1 or more widget responses in a JSON wrapper.  Thus we can do retrievals in these ways:

- Single Widget Retrieval
- Multiple (Aggregate) Widget Retrieval - We are requesting data for 2 or more widgets at a time.

in a single call to the server.

---

### Deliver Data to Widget Controllers from an Aggregated Retrieval

1) **Aggregated Retrieval**: We have an AngualrJS “page” controller that is responsible for making the aggregated retrieval for all the widgets on the page upon page load. It makes the request for all 5 widgets on the page by delegating the AJAX request to an Ng factory to handle data retrieval—we’ll call that “PageResourceFactory”.

2) **Forward to Individual Widget ResourceFactories**: Upon successfully getting data back the “PageResourceFactory”, it calls another factory helper to forward the relevant responses to the individual widget resource factories calling their set methods.  Thus at this point, all 5 widget resource factories have their data set.

3) **Widget Controllers Subscribe to New Data**: During page initialization each widget controller has already setup a subscription to their own resource factories to essentially listen for when new data has been set (via their resource factory set methods). THUS, the controllers can know when the data has changed (whether or not they the widget controller initiated a retrieval or not).

4) **Widget Controllers Bind Data**: Each widget controller is ‘notified’ of a data change, and thus can respond accordingly by putting it on the scope to bind to the view.

### Single Retrieval

This works just a standard AJAX retrieval.
1) Controller makes request via a resource factory.

2) The resource factory with the aid of $http performs the AJAX request and passes the promise object back up the the controller.

3) The controller takes the data (after a successful promise call) and binds it for the view to display.

---

This is the way we approached the problem.  I'm sure there are other possibilities.